# firemonkey drawings on bitmap without BeginScene and EndScene

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

I am developing an application that should be drawing vector based like graphics.  I am drawing a lot of lines (more than 50 000) on the image.  After playing around and doing some research it seems like the bottleneck is caused by the Image.Beginscene and Image.Endscene - [Fastest way to draw pixels in FireMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988131/fastest-way-to-draw-pixels-in-firemonkey).  Is there any way to draw lines without the BeginScene and EndScene?

Answer (score 1):

We was recently tuning the speed of the firemonkey and we found following:

1) because of the beginScene and EndScene you don't need any secondary buffer. You can write directly to the canvas that is visible and the changes are populated after EndScrene without any flickering.

2) The pasting of images is extremely fast, even large images.

3) Lines,rectangles,etc. are average fast.

4) Texts are extremely slow.

So if you can use some buffers and paint part of the lines to the TBitmap, then past the TBitmap every time you are building scene and use paint only on lines that changes it would give you speed you are looking for.

Comment: One of the big issues is when I am zooming for example.  Then all the lines need to be redrawn.  This causes my image to lag a lot.  Can you maybe suggest how I should use a buffer?  Thanx

Comment: well I don't know you are app, but as the images are super fast, even the zooming can be handled by zooming of the image. Like when you zoom the google maps - they first stretch the image and after the loading they show you the content. If I would be you, I'll do something like that.

Comment: I suppose this could work.  However this raises a new question : is it possible to first stretch the image and then redraw the image in one method without using multi threading? I am worried that the redrawing might also slow down the stretching.

Comment: yes, you can paint stretched image very fast without speed penalty.

Comment: Yes, but after the stretch I will need to redraw.  So if I stretch and redraw in the same method the screen will only update after the redraw so the stretch will never happen.  Any ideas on how to first stretch the image, update the screen and then redraw?

Comment: Why you not stretch and redraw in thread and once you are done with redraw, update scene with redrawed bitmap?

Comment: Been trying to work with threads in FireMonkey.  I just can't get it to work

Comment: And what was the problem?